# Why the move-constructor is not called ? (only the constuctor by default, and nothing else)

Tags: c++, constructor, variable-assignment

Could you explain me why, in the following, code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>



class MySecondType {
public:
    MySecondType() { std::cout << "Constructeur par défaut de MySecondType\n"; }
    MySecondType(const MySecondType&) // Constructeur par copie
    {std::cout<< "Constructeur par copie de MySecondType\n";}
    MySecondType(MySecondType&&) noexcept//Constructeur par déplacement 
    {
        std::cout << "COnstructeur par déplacement de MySecondType\n";
    }


    MySecondType& operator=(MySecondType&&) noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "Opérateur d'affection par déplacement\n";
        return *this;
    }

    MySecondType& operator=(MySecondType&) 
    {
        std::cout << "Opérateur d'affection par copie\n";
        return *this;
    }



    ~MySecondType() {
        std::cout << "Destructeur de MySecondType\n";
    }

};


int main() {

    MySecondType e;
    e= MySecondType() ;
return 0;
}
```

I have the result I wait, with :

```
MySecondType e;
e= MySecondType() ;
```

BUT I don't have it , if I do :

```
MySecondType e = MySecondType() ;
```

I expected that the line :

`MySecondType e = MySecondType() ;`

would call the move constructor(after the default constructor), but it does not call it. It only creates an object with the default constructor , and that's nothing else.

Can you explain me why ?

Thank you

Comment: You need to assign to a variable. try `MySecondType e = MySecondType()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Comment: FYI: [SO: What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12953129/7478597). For the record: `MySecondType e;
e= MySecondType();` is assignment but `MySecondType e = MySecondType() ;` is initialization. About, `MySecondType = MySecondType();` (with missing variable name) I'm not 100 % sure but I strongly guess it's the same.

Comment: I have edited the message and added the missing e when it was missing

Comment: Note that your copy construcor is incorrect, it takes its argument by non-const lvalue-reference, while it should be taking it by const lvalue-reference.

Comment: I think you better mean my copy assignment operator, not my copy constructor , which is correct.

Comment: @Darhuuk the non-const version is legal, but it's considered bad style

Comment: @Dev Indeed, I meant the copy assignment operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm asuming you actually do what @Jacob hinted at, i.e. `MySecondType e = MySecondType();`.

If so, then the compiler is eliding the copy/move constructor. It sees that you are creating a temporary object and right after assigning it to a variable. So instead of doing that, which would be inefficient, it skips the copy/move step and directly constructs the object at its final destination.

AFAIK, this is an optional optimization pre-C++17. Starting in C++17 it's mandatory.